# Protractor: How to resolve promise and stop skipping of scenarios if one scenario fails

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I have a Protarctor-CucumberJS framework and a suite of test scenarios.
When I execute the entire suite, one script fails at an expect (ChaiJS) statement.

```
Scenario 1  : Passed
Scenario 2  : Passed
Scenario 3  : Failed (Unresolved Promise)
Scenario 4  : Skipped
Scenario 5  : Skipped
Scenario 6  : Skipped
Scenario 7  : Skipped
Scenario 8  : Skipped
Scenario 9  : Skipped
Scenario 10 : Skipped
```

The step definition of that particular step looks like this:

```
Then('I verify if valid success message received as {string}', function (successMessage) {
    expect($(.abc).getText()).to.eventually.equal(successMessage);
});
```

Due to a defect, app is not showing an error, the element: $(".abc") is not displayed on screen and this scenario fails after 30 seconds of function time-out. Complete error is pasted below. But the problem is all other scenarios after this are skipped with the same error message.

> Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 30000 milliseconds
>       at Timeout._time.default.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (C:\bla\bla\node_modules\cucumber\lib\user_code_runner.js:81:20)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
>       at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
>       at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)

Questions:

1. How can I avoid skipping of preceding scenarios if one scenario fails?
2. How to resolve the promise in situations like above.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to use `async` functions? If so you could try with a conditional for if the element is present or not, something like this:

```
    Then('I verify if valid success message received as {string}', async function (successMessage, done) {
        const abcElement = await $(.abc).isPresent();
        if (abcElement) {
            expect(await $(.abc).getText()).to.eventually.equal(successMessage);
            done();
        } else {
            done();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Also I have used async functions too. That didn't effect in my case.

Comment: async/await is just an _easier_ way to handle promises imo. You could try creating getText/click/etc functions with explicit waits inside so you don't repeat too much code

Comment: Yeah. That can really help but i will have to update my existing code. That takes much effort.

Comment: you can always change your `allScriptsTimeout` value in the conf.js file. It looks like is set to 30 secs, you could try lowering it to see what happens

Comment: I have used setDefaultTimeout(30 *1000) in my BeforeAll hook. If I reduce it, it's Timed out like in 20 sec or 10 sec etc..

Comment: I have started to think about your solution seriously. I'm looking for one more info from your code sample above. Can you explain what;s the significance of 'done' argument of function and what happens when you call done()?

Comment: It's a way to _let_ your app to _know_ when your task is complete when doing async work, like in the example I gave you. It's also pretty useful if you want to fail a case if something goes wrong. In my example you could do `done.fail('something');` in the `else` block

Comment: That helps. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I tried to use your code and I see error, can you help me resolve it: 
Error: function uses multiple asynchronous interfaces: callback and promise
       to use the callback interface: do not return a promise
       to use the promise interface: remove the last argument to the function

Comment: Here is my code, you might have to format it to view properly:
When('I click on {string}', async function(eleName, done){
    let ele=eval(eleName);

    if (typeof ele !== 'undefined') {
        if (ele.isPresent()) {
            await ele.click();
            done();
        }else{
            done.fail("Error: Element " + eleName + " not present on the screen");
        }
    } else {
        done.fail("Error: Unable to find the element " + eleName + " in the page class.");
    }
});

Comment: what are you passing through 'eleName' ? The whole `if typeOf` conditional might not be needed

Comment: My way of implementation is little different. "eleName" is actually element name I'm sending from the Gherkin step as parameter. My elements are in a constructor of a class. The line "eval(eleName)" actually returns the element based on element name I'm sending from a step. This is to make the step definition reusable. just need to say: `When I click on "dealPage.addIssuer"` or `When I click on "productPage.dealName"` etc.
Saying that, The error occurred at the line: `done.fail("");`. Actually `if typeOf` checks if the element returned successfully.

Comment: So that, I can fail if the element not found in the repository class.